# Continuity of a bijection

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, baire-category

Let y be a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)^2$. 
Goal: Prove that y is not continuous.

Idea to start the proof: Makes sense assume $f$ is continuous, consider $(0,1)$ as the union of the closed intervals $[1/k, 1-1/k]$ where k goes from $1$ to $\infty$ and consider Baire's theorems:

- Suppose $C_1, C_2, \dots$ is a countable collection of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the union from $n = 1$ to $\infty$ of $C_n$ contains an open set $O$. Then at least one of these closed sets contains an open set.
- Let $(M, D)$ be a complete metric space. Suppose $M$ is a countable union of closed sets of $M$. Then one of these closed sets contains an open set of $M$.
- Baire Category Theorem

Any hint it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: An injective continuous function on a compact metric space is a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: I'm curious: should the OP apply this to closed subsets of $(0,1)$?  The metric space is $(0,1)$ isn't compact.

Comment: The compact set of choice would be one of the $[1/k,1-1/k]$ the OP discussed.

Comment: I wrote a proper proof (not my first,erroneous "proof" for the wrong Q) and discarded it because I'm very sleepy and I'm sure it was correct,but almost nobody would want to slog through it.Tomorrow I'll try to post a civilized proof.